# What is a type in Wolfram Mathematica programming language?

Tags: programming, symbolic

"Everything is an expression" is a popular citation from many *Mathematica* guidebooks. So, what is type in *Mathematica*? How does it relate to common types from Haskell, for example?

I did some *simulation* of dependent types:

```
DependentType::illegal= "Value is illegal for dependent types with constraints";
FixedSizedVector[n_?(Positive[#]&)] :=
Module[{type = Symbol["Vector" <> ToString[n]]},
    type[dat_] := Message[DependentType::illegal] /; VectorQ[dat] && Length[dat] != n;
    type
];
types =
Map[
    FixedSizedVector[#]&,
    Range[1, 25]
];
```

I have received an array `types` of symbols that are constrained with pattern checking rules. Is it a family of types?

Another point is `Head` replacing. For example, for list `Range[1, 5]` I can just type `Plus @@ Range[1, 5]` and get `Integer[15]`. From the point of view of type, what is `Apply`?

Comment: "Mathematica ... gets great flexibility precisely from avoiding the use of types." -Stephen Wolfram

Comment: I rather say that Mathematica introduces a new "dimension" called "Expression" in the flat model "types -> values". Expressions make that model to commute: one can get from types to values and vice versa. So Mathematica's approach is a flexible way to do "types <-> values" model.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The nearest Mathematica has to "types" are Heads of expressions that are Atoms. For example:

```
Through[{AtomQ, Head}[2]]

{True, Integer}

Through[{AtomQ, Head}[2 + I]]

{True, Complex}

Through[{AtomQ, Head}["cat"]]

{True, String}
```

and so on...

There are also somewhat different "types" in the context of Compile.

Comment: Thank you for response! So, is it correct to claim that Mathematica has not types as they are in strict-typed languages replacing them with a more generalized notion of expression? Types and values are expressions, so programmer has an ability to switch between them (as I modeled with some kind of dependent types in question body).

Comment: I think this is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Just a single extra detail: not only `Symbol` can be interpret as a type, but any unevaluated/evaluated expression. So my last question for this topic is: does Mathematica provide a language that cannot be explained by traditional theory of types? Are there existed any papers about Mathematica programming language semantics?

Comment: Mathematica is a symbolic programming language see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430998/mathematica-what-is-symbolic-programming. Also the book "Structure and interpretation of computer programs" by Abelson et al. deals with concepts relevant to Mathematica.

Comment: Let me add to the above. In programming language theory a Type is not just a set of values, but also the operations available to them. In Mathematica a value with a particular head can be considered of that 'type' but regarding the operations available to such head, Mathematica allows you to add and remove rules for those values, so types are defined at runtime and can change. In addition, upvalues and downvalues enrich the picture quite a bit.

Answer (score 18):

In Mathematica, the type of a built-in object is represented by the `Head`. For example, `Head[3]` is `Integer`, `Head[1.5]` is `Real` and `Head[a]` is `Symbol` (assuming that `a` hasn't been assigned a value, of course, because in that case, you'll get the `Head` of that value).

Note that for expressions of the form `foo[bar,baz]`, the head is `foo`. Most expressions are internally represented in such a form, as can be seen by applying `FullForm`, for example:

```
{1, 2, 3}//FullForm
(*
==> List[1, 2, 3]
*)
a + b //FullForm
(*
==> Plus[a, b]
*)
```

and consequently the `Head` gives `List` in the first case, and `Plus` in the second case.

**Edit**

Note that Mathematica evaluates the expression given to `Head` if possible, so the result of `Head[1+2]` is *not* `Plus` but `Integer` because `Head` is replaced only after evaluating `1+2` which gives the value `3` of type `Integer`. On the other hand, `Head[a+b]` gives `Plus` (assuming neither `a` nor `b` have any applicable definition), because `a+b` is "inert" under evaluation: There are no evaluation rules which could applied to it, therefore it is self-evaluating. Note that the same is true for head replacing (`Apply`, `@@`). Also note in that context that Mathematica, unlike the typical functional language, continues evaluation until it reaches an "inert" expression which cannot be further evaluated. This is best demonstrated by the following Mathematica code:

```
foo := bar;
bar := 3;
foo
(*
==> 3
*)
```

Here in the first step, Mathematica evaluates `foo`, which evaluates to `bar`. But it doesn't stop there, but continues to evaluate `bar` which gives the result `3`. Now that result cannot be further evaluated, and therefore is given as the result. On the other hand, the seemingly equivalent Lisp code

```
(progn
  (setq foo 'bar)
  (setq bar 'baz)
  foo)
```

will evaluate to `bar` because after evaluating `foo` to `bar`, Lisp doesn't try to re-evaluate.

To see how this interacts with head replacing, consider the following code:

```
Plus@@Range[1,5]
(*
==> 15
*)
```

In the first step, `Range[1,5]` is evaluated, giving `{1,2,3,4,5}`, that is `List[1,2,3,4,5]` with head `List`. Now `Apply` replaces the head of *that* expression with `Plus`, resulting in `Plus[1,2,3,4,5]`, that is `1+2+3+4+5`. Now that is again an evaluatable expression, evaluating to `15` which as an "inert" expression is the final result.

Note that you can prevent Mathematica from evaluating an argument before calling a function by using `Unevaluated`. For example, `Head[Unevaluated[Range[1,5]]]` gives `Range`, and `Plus@@Unevaluated[Range[1,5]]` gives `6` (because the `Range` got replaced by `Plus`, and then the resulting expression is evaluated). In this respect, `Unevaluated` is similar to Lisp's `quote`. Note however that due to Mathematica's continuing evaluation, the effects can be drastically different. For example, consider the code

```
f[x_]:=x
f[Unevaluated[1+1]]
(*
==> 2
*)
```

You might expect this to return `1+1` unevaluated, just like the corresponding Lisp code with `quote` does. However while `Unevaluated` indeed causes `1+1` to be passed to `f` without further evaluation, applying the definition of `f` results in `1+1` (note: *without* the `Unevaluated`!), which Mathematica continues to evaluate, resulting in `2`.

Comment: This also applies to types of numbers, like `Head/@ {0.5, 1, I, 3/2} == {Real, Integer, Complex, Rational}`. Although they also considered atomic (`AtomQ/@ {0.5, 1, I, 3/2} == {True, True, True, True}`) and are treated subtly differently by some functions, like `Map` primarily operates on atoms, yet `Apply` does not.

Comment: Thank you for responses! `Head` is the case, but I have some problems with that. In Mathematica, all is an expression such as functions and values are. So how should I interpret head replacing? For example, `Range[1, 5]` returns list but it has `Head` `Range`. And it becomes just a `Integer` if we replace its `Head` with `Plus`: `Plus @@ Range[1, 5]` is just `Integer[15]`

Comment: @spk: While the expression `Range[1,5]` has head `Range`, it *evaluates* to {1,2,3,4,5} with head `List`. Similarly, `Plus@@Range[1,5]` first evaluates `Range[1,5]` to {1,2,3,4,5}, *then* replaces the head (`List`) with `Plus`, giving `Plus[1,2,3,4,5]`, i.e. 1+2+3+4+5, which evaluates to 15. Note that a difference between M'a and typical functional languages is that M'a continues evaluating until there's nothing left which could be evaluated. For example, in M'a `foo:=bar;bar:=3;foo` evaluates to `3`, while e.g. in Lisp `(progn (setq foo ´bar) (setq bar 3) foo)` evaluates to `bar`.

Comment: @celtschk That comment is probably worth working into your answer.

Comment: @BrettChampion: Done.

Answer (score 8):

Since *Mathematica* 10, there is the `` TypeSystem` `` Context, that is nearly what you might be looking for. It is just a wrapper around patterns.

```
TypeSystem`ConformsQ[
  {1, 2, 3}, 
  TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`IntegerT, 3]
]  (* --> True *)
```

It is the thing being used internally by Dataset-related functions. (Maybe one should say something like `Dataset[{}]` first to beable to use the TypeSystem; I’m too lazy to check again whether it is necessary.)

Unfortunately, it is not documented but you can figure it out looking at names in `` ?TypeSystem`* `` and at `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions @ TypeSystem`Validation`PackagePrivate`vtor ``.

`` TypeSystem`Either `` is (was?) not working as expected, but see my [patch](https://github.com/McSaks/wl-init/blob/master/TypeSystemEither.m).

Answer (score 4):

In Mathematica, *values* are expressions.

*Types* in computer science are collections of values.

Perhaps a type in Mathematica could be viewed as a pattern which matches a certain class of expressions.

Programming language designers often classify values according to the different roles that different types of values are allowed to play in that language.  For example, in functional languages, *functions* are often described as "first-class citizens" because they can be passed as parameters to functions and returned as values from functions, much like atomic data types such as integers and strings.

Mathematica is very flexible in that (like S-expressions in LISP) values can play any role for which meaningful transformation rules are defined that match those values (perhaps as part of a larger expression).  Viewing types as patterns that describe the class of expressions that the pattern matches, one could ask what does it mean then to "instantiate" a value of a certain type in Mathematica ... in analogy to instantiating an object (*i.e.* a value) in say Java of the abstract data type described by the class definition?

When the kernel reads in any expression that matches that pattern (even if no explicit pattern matching is requested) one could say that a value of the pattern type has been instantiated (through the act of parsing the expression).  So here is one sense in which the notion of types as patterns may be a little more general than how this term is used in other programming languages like Java.  The pattern-as-type notion of type allows one to test for type membership, which is useful for verifying program correctness, making internal optimizations, etc.  But it is also possible to instantiate a value of a given type (actually of an infinite number of different types) without ever defining the type (i.e. specifying a pattern that matches the type) explicitly as in a class definition.

So in Mathematica, all conceivable types already exist implicitly (which perhaps helps clarify the Wolfram quote in the response to the OP).  The patterns are then like names that explicitly describe types when one wants to use them for testing say membership in a certain class of expressions defined by the type pattern ... perhaps much like lambda expressions name the anonymous functions that they define at time and place of use.

Or maybe not ... anyone else have any thoughts here?

Comment: I suppose, types aka patterns is a very nice interpretation. I also see that this is a more general notion than type from classical programming languages.

Comment: It's worth pointing out here that patterns themselves are valid expressions in Mathematica.  Clearly Mathematica is just one of many programming languages today that treats types as values.  Part of what makes Mathematica so appealing however is the diversity of complex data types that can be easily created on the fly using its rich pattern-matching syntax.

Comment: Your point describes the Mathematica world only partially. Mathematica does not introduces the notion of the type at all. It uses only `List` with special treatment of the first element called `Head`. This concept allows anybody to emulate any known type system. Also it makes Mathematica to have the most flexible programming language I have ever seen. However, it must be noted that Mathematica is an interpretator. So it is impossible to split the program life-cycle into the compile-time and run-time.