# Does every Symbol in Mathematica induce a monad?

Tags: programming, functional-style, symbols

From my [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/what-is-a-type-in-wolfram-mathematica-programming-language) about types in Mathematica, I assume that every `Symbol` in Mathematica is a type if it appears as a `Head` of some expression.

So I can implement operators for monad associated with that `Symbol` (let it be `F` for instance):

1. monad *lift* function (*return* in Haskell notation) is just `return[p_] = F[p]`;
2. monad *bind* function (*>>=* in Haskell notation) is just a rule `bind[F[p_], f_] := F[f[p]]` (as monad [Maybe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#Maybe_monad) is for example).

From point of view of category theory, in Mathematica one can define some common rules for symbols to model monad multiplication (just flatten of repeating `Head`): `monadMultiplyRule = {p_[p_[params___]] -> p[params]}`. So expression `F[F[F[p_]]] //. monadMultiplyRule` will be just `F[p]`.

Also all monad axioms are satisfied:

1. `return` acts as a neutral element of `bind`: `bind[return[p], f]` is `F[f[p]]` and
   `bind[F[p], Identity]` is `F[p]`;
2. sequential `bind` of two functions `f` and `q` is the same as a single `bind` with their 
   "composition" `Bind[F[f[p]], q]`:
   `Bind[Bind[F[p], f], q]` and `Bind[F[f[p]], q]` produce both the same result `F[q[f[p]]]`.

So, does Mathematica provide a natural maybe-like monad for every symbol and does it provide a natural framework for any explicit monadic computations?

Comment: Very nice question! I too am familier with haskell and the other functional languages. However, I'm unaware of any monadic builtins within _Mathematica_ proper. _Mathematica_ is essentially a glorified pattern matcher, which means it ought to be possible to write a Monadic extension to MMA using the ``Notation` `` package to implement monadic operators. _When I get a chance later today, I may expand this comment to a proper answer, but I think this might get folks thinking in the meantime._

Comment: The more I think about your question the more I think the answer is _yes_ to the question in the title. But _not sure_ (I need to think) and _no_ to the questions at the end. There is no natural framework for explicit monadic computations in _Mathematica_ like that which exists in Haskell that I am aware of. But! There is nothing stopping us from "hacking" in one as folks do to emulate OOP style programming. I'll try to formulate a proper answer soonish.

Comment: The comments of @nixeagle are mostly correct but given with the wrong attitude. **1)** Monad programming is not that needed in Mathematica, and it is not a paradigm to be look up to. **2)** Monad programming is easily done in Mathematica, using Mathematica's core principles.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mathematica provides a perfect way to define monad by setting `UpValues` and `DownValues` of some symbol. Please, find specifications for monads Maybe and State below.

1. Monad Maybe:

   ```
   DownValues[Just] = {Just[(a: Just[x_])] :> Just[x]};
   UpValues[Just] = 
       {(expr: (op: Except[Just | List | Trace | UpValues | DownValues])[
          a___, Just[b_], c___]) /;  
          !MatchQ[
              Unevaluated[expr],
              HoldPattern[If[__, __, Just[x_]] | If[__, Just[x_], __]]
          ] :> Just[op[a, b, c]]};
   ```

   Rule from `DownValues[Just]` stands for monad Maybe multiplication law. That is removing of head duplicates. Rule from `UpValues[Just]` stands for bind operation of monad Maybe. One need to use special pre-condition for this pattern because Mathematica uses some wrapping code to convert evaluating/reducing expression in standard form by low-level call `MakeBoxes`. For example, let's see this wrapping code:

   ```
   Hold[
    If[False, 3,
     With[{OutputSizeLimit`Dump`boxes$ =
        Block[{$RecursionLimit = Typeset`$RecursionLimit},
         MakeBoxes[Just[3], StandardForm]
         ]
       },
      OutputSizeLimit`Dump`loadSizeCountRules[]; 
      If[TrueQ[BoxForm`SizeCount[OutputSizeLimit`Dump`boxes$, 1048576]], 
       OutputSizeLimit`Dump`boxes$,
       OutputSizeLimit`Dump`encapsulateOutput[
        Just[3],
        $Line,
        $SessionID,
        5
        ]
       ]
      ],
     Just[3]
     ]
    ]
   ```

   That's why rule from `UpValues[Just]` has special pre-condition for being inside of condition expression. Now one can use symbol `Just` as a head for computations with exceptions:

   ```
   UpValues[Nothing] = {_[___, Nothing, ___] :> Nothing};
   Just[Just[123]]
   (*
    ==> Just[123]
   *)

   Just[123] + Just[34] - (Just[1223]/Just[12321])*Just[N[Sqrt[123]]]
   (*
    ==> Just[155.899]
   *)
   ```

   Thanks to @celtschk for great comments of this point.
2. Monad State:

   ```
   return[x_] := State[s \[Function] {x, s}];
   bind[m_State, f_] := State[r \[Function] (f[#[[1]]][#[[2]]] & @ Part[m, 1][r])];
   runState[s_, State[f_]] := f[s];
   ```

   For monad State I didn't use `UpValues` and `DownValues` just for similarity with Haskell notation. Now, one can define some sequential computation as State value with complex state logics as a monadic computation by using `return` and `bind` operations. Please, see an example:

   ```
   computation =
     Fold[bind, return[1], 
      Join[{a \[Function] s \[Function] {a, a + s}, 
        b \[Function] s \[Function] {b, s + b/(3 s)}, 
        c \[Function] s \[Function] {c, s + (s^2 + c)}},
       Array[x \[Function] a \[Function] s \[Function] {a, s}, 300]
       ]
      ];
   ```

   To get more effective computation one can use `runState` operation:

   ```
   Fold[#2[#1[[1]]][#1[[2]]] &, runState[23, return[1]], 
       Join[{a \[Function] s \[Function] {a, a + s}, 
             b \[Function] s \[Function] {b, s + b/(3 s)}, 
             c \[Function] s \[Function] {c, s + (s^2 + c)}},
            Array[x \[Function] a \[Function] s \[Function] {a, s}, 3000]
     ]
    ]
    (*
     ==> {1, 3119113/5184}
    *)
   ```

Conclusion:

1. Ideas of rule-based programming and using `Head` as type identifier allow user to express any(?) programming concept in Mathematica. For example, as it has just been shown, monads State and Maybe from Haskell;
2. Using of `UpValues` and `DownValues` for assigning rules to symbols and using of generalized operations (such as `bind` is) allow user to put expressions in different monadic environments.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this alternative approach is useful?  Many years ago, before I stumbled on this site, I wrote a package for monad comprehensions with parallel generators (think `Thread`), which I found a very useful feature of early Haskell compilers and missed in MMA.  I simply implemented the formal semantics given in a paper I found on the topic.  I added some syntax with the `Notation` package which allows me to write things such as:

[image: syntax examples of monad comprehensions]

```
SetAttributes[comprehend,HoldRest]

comprehend[m_, e_, True]:= unit[m][e]
comprehend[m_, e_, q_]  := comprehend[m,e,q,True]

comprehend[m_,e_,generator[p_,l_],q__]:=
  Module[{ok}, ok[_]:=zero[m]; ok[p]:=comprehend[m, e, q]; bind[m][ok,l]]

comprehend[m_,e_,zipgen[gens__],q__]:=
  Block[{x},
    comprehend[m, e, 
      generator[comprehend[m,x,generator[generator[x_,_],    
        {gens}]], 
           zipping[m][comprehend[m,l, generator[generator[_,l_],{gens}]]]],q]]

(*  assume everything not a generator or a parallel generator is a test *)
comprehend[m_,e_,b_,q__]:=If[b,comprehend[m,e,q],zero[m]]

zero[Maybe] := None
unit[Maybe] := Some
bindMaybe[_,None] := None
bindMaybe[f_,Some[x_]] := f[x]
bind[Maybe] := bindMaybe
zipping[Maybe] := (Message[comprehend::nozip,Maybe];zipping[])

zero[List]:={}
unit[List]:={#}&
bind[List]:=Flatten[#1 /@ #2,1]&
zipping[List]:=Thread

pluck[e_,l_] := Block[{x},comprehend[List,x,generator[x_,l],x=!=e]]

removeDups[{}] := {}
removeDups[{h_,l___}] := Prepend[pluck[h,removeDups[{l}]],h]

zero[Sets] := {}
unit[Sets] := {#}&
bind[Sets] := removeDups[Flatten[#1 /@ #2,1]]&
zipping[Sets] := (Message[comprehend::nozip,Sets];zipping[])

zero::usage="The zero of a monad (if any)";
unit::usage="The unit of a monad";
bind::usage="The bind function of a monad";
zipping::usage="The zipper for a monad (if any)";
comprehend::usage="A monad comprehension (requires a zero)";
zipgen::usage="The constructor for parallel generation";
generator::usage="The constructor for generation";
comprehend::nozip="Zipping not implemented for `1`";
removeDups::usage="Remove duplicates from a list";
Maybe::usage="The (name of the) Maybe monad";
Sets::usage="The (name of the) Set monad";
```

I'd be interested if anyone finds this adds something useful.

Comment: Interesting post from a didactic point of view (especially for comparisons with Haskell, Scala, F#), but not that useful because: **(1)** the posted code needs more explanations (or related links) and better usages examples, and **(2)** the programmed comprehension functionalities are easily done with the core Mathematica/WL functions.

Comment: You are right that the code needs more explanations.  I think the comprehensions style is easier for many (including me) to read and understand, especially if there is existing familiarity with set theory.  I would like to make the case that code can be clearer and more easily modified using this style, which is probably why the implementors of e.g. Haskell's comprehensions syntax decided to do it (comprehensions are readily defined from other monadic functions, or directly using core language functions, this applies as well to Haskell as to WL).  I'll provide some better examples when I can.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Do you mind posting it as a response in the discussion ["How and why to use monadic programming in Mathematica?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147679/34008)? (Probably, together with other explanations as your answer opening.)

Answer (score 2):

> Does every Symbol in Mathematica induce a monad?

Yes, [the monad laws](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws) are satisfied for every symbol in Mathematica with `List` being the unit operation and `Apply` being the binding operation.

[image]

> So, does Mathematica provide a natural maybe-like monad for every symbol [...]

In view of the monad laws satisfaction table above the answer is "yes, kind of."

> [...] and does it provide a natural framework for any explicit monadic computations?

I would say the answer is "yes" to this question. I think this way of [programming of the Maybe monad](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148935/34008) is fairly straightforward.

A general approach for working with monads is described in the blog post ["Monad code generation and extension"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2017/06/23/monad-code-generation-and-extension/) (or see [Markdown version at GitHub](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MarkdownDocuments/Monad-code-generation-and-extension.md).) That approach does not take the "algebraic type" perspective on monad programming, it uses code generation instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your explanation correctly, the following definitions should implement a Maybe monad:

```
_[___, Nothing, ___] ^:= Nothing;
Just[Just[a_]]:=Just[a]
Just/:(f:Except[Just])[a___,Just[b_],c___]:=Just[f[a,b,c]]
```

Now you may write e.g.

```
Just[2]+Just[3]
(*
==> Just[5]
*)
2+Just[3]
(*
==> Just[5]
*)
2+Nothing
(*
==> Nothing
*)
```

Note however that this does not play nice with Mathematica's special functions, e.g.

```
Hold[Just[3]]
(*
==> Just[Hold[3]]
*)
```

Of course one would want that expression to remain unevaluated.

One solution to this would be to replace `Except[Just]` by `Except[Just|Hold|HoldForm|Trace|TracePrint]` and just hope that no function has been forgotten. Or maybe one should just exclude all functions having a `Hold*` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for a nice answer! I thought about solution like yours. But in Mathematica 8 I have next problem: `UpValues[Just] = {Just[Just[x_]] :> 
    Just[x], (op : Except[Just])[a___, Just[b_], c___] :> 
    Just[op[a, b, c]]}; Plus[Just[2], 3]` does not works as `patterns = {Just[Just[x_]] :> 
    Just[x], (op : Except[Just])[a___, Just[b_], c___] :> 
    Just[op[a, b, c]]}; Plus[Just[2], 3] //. patterns`. For first way, answer will be `Just[Just[Just[5]]]`. And for second way, answer will be as I expected: `Just[5]`. Do you know the reason of this?

Comment: @spk: You have to wrap the left side of the rules in `HoldPattern`: `patterns={HoldPattern[Just[Just[x_]]]:> Just[x], HoldPattern[(op : Except[Just])[a___, Just[b_], c___]]:> Just[op[a, b, c]]}; Plus[Just[2], 3] //. patterns` gives `Just[5]`, and the same is true for `UpValues`.

Comment: `HoldPattern` is a good point, but pattern `(op: Except[Just])[a___, Just`[b_], c___]` can match expressions like ``Just[Just[x_]]` because Mathematica convert each value to standard boxes by low-level call of `MakeBoxes`. So define monad "bind" pattern as `UpValues[Just] = {HoldPattern[(op: Except[Just])[a___, Just[b_], c___]] :> Hold[op[a, b, c]]}`. Then Mathematica produces some deboxing code (and cheking current session params) for value `Just[Just[3]]`. So one has to check this to define correct rules for Maybe monad.

Comment: Please, see my answer below for monads Maybe and State.

Comment: I think your comment on the behavior of Hold is misplaced. It is doing exactly what should be expected, Hold isen't intended to prevent UpValues. If you want to protect against UpValues, you should use HoldComplete. This behavoir is also documented in the documentation center of Hold.

Comment: @jVincent: That is not a comment on the behaviour of `Hold`, it is a comment on the behaviour on the implementation of monads using `UpValues`. The user of `Just` doesn't care if it is implemented with `UpValues`, `DownValues` or magic. The user of `Just` only cares that it behaves as he expects such a monad to behave. And there's IMHO no reason to expect it to be unaffected by `Hold` (again, the implementation using `UpValues` is an *implementation detail* the user is not supposed to have to care about).

Comment: @celtschk Then I might be misunderstanding you. Isn't it behaving exactly like you would want, with f[Just[2]] returning Just[f[2]], but f being Hold? I thought you where commenting on this being unusual from a Mathematica point of view, since naively users expect Hold[f[2]] be remain unevaluated.

Comment: The point is exactly that `Hold[Just[2]]` should not be evaluated. It *is* evaluated because `Just` is implemented with `UpValues`, but the fact that `Just` is implemented with `UpValues` is an implementation detail that users should not have to care about. Therefore it is a bug in the implementation of `Just` that `Hold` doesn't hold it. As I wrote, this can be fixed with an `Except` in the rule.

Answer (score -1):

I have been trying to find out how to use Either/Maybe type in Mathematica.

Unfortunately algebraic data type doesn't work very well in Mathematica, some data type definitions are complex.

I have come up a method to use them without define them. I defined Maybe type in functions.

Please notes that there are a couple of incorrect examples in some answers, for instance,

```
Just[3] + Just[5] == Just[8]
Just[Just[3]] == Just[3]
```

Maybe type doesn't work like this.

Maybe type is like a box, either it's Just a value, or it's Nothing. Before you use it, you have to unwrap the box and use the value or Nothing directly or indirectly.

**Maybe**

In:

```
Maybe[a_] := Just | $Nothing (*Do nothing, it's like a comment*)

fromJust
(*The fromJust function extracts the element out of a Just and throws \
an error if its argument is Nothing.*)

fromJust::argx = "`` is not Just";
fromJust[Just[a_]] := a
fromJust[x_] := Message[fromJust::argx, x]

fromJust[Just[3]]
fromJust[$Nothing]
fromJust[Just[Just[x]]]

fromMaybe
(*The fromMaybe function takes a default value and and Maybe value.If \
the Maybe is Nothing,it returns the default values;otherwise,it \
returns the value contained in the Maybe.*)

fromMaybe::argx = "`` is not Maybe";
fromMaybe[a_, Just[x_]] := x
fromMaybe[a_, $Nothing] := a
fromMaybe[a_, _] := Message[fromMaybe::argx, x]

fromMaybe[0, Just[100]]
fromMaybe[0, $Nothing]
fromMaybe[0, t]

LiftM2
(*Promote a function to a monad,scanning the monadic arguments from \
left to right.For example*)

LiftM2::argx = "Either `` or `` is not Maybe";
LiftM2[f_, Just[a_], Just[b_]] := Just@f[a, b]
LiftM2[f_, $Nothing, _] := $Nothing
LiftM2[f_, _, $Nothing] := $Nothing
LiftM2[f_, x_, y_] := Message[LiftM2::argx, x, y]

LiftM2[#1 + #2 &, Just[3], Just[4]]
LiftM2[#1 + #2 &, Just[5], $Nothing]
LiftM2[#1 + #2 &, t, 3]
```

Out:

[image]

**Monad Maybe**

The definition of Monad Maybe is simple.

```
Just[x_] \[CirclePlus] g_ := g[x]
$Nothing  \[CirclePlus] g_ := $Nothing
```

And it's a powerful technique.

If there is a task which has 3 subtasks. Any subtasks can go wrong, it either returns Nothing or a Just value. If any subtask goes wrong, the whole task should be stopped immediately. Before you read further, you could think how you implement it.

Implementation:

```
ClearAll[f, g, CirclePlus, debug, clean, build, combine]

Just[x_] \[CirclePlus] g_ := g[x]
$Nothing  \[CirclePlus] g_ := $Nothing

CirclePlus[f_, g_, h__] := (f \[CirclePlus] g)\[CirclePlus]h
CirclePlus[f_, g_] := f \[CirclePlus] g

debug[name_, Just[x_]] := (Print@name; Just[x])

1
ClearAll[clean, build, combine]
clean[x_] := (Print["Failed: clean"]; $Nothing)
clean[100] \[CirclePlus] build \[CirclePlus] combine

2
ClearAll[clean, build, combine]
clean[x_] := debug[clean, Just[x + 1]]
build[x_] := (Print["Failed: build"]; $Nothing)
clean[100] \[CirclePlus] build \[CirclePlus] combine

3
ClearAll[clean, build, combine]
clean[x_] := debug[clean, Just[x + 1]]
build[x_] := debug[build, Just[x + 1]]
combine[x_] := (Print["Failed: combine"]; $Nothing)
clean[100] \[CirclePlus] build \[CirclePlus] combine

4
ClearAll[clean, build, combine]
clean[x_] := debug[clean, Just[x + 1]]
build[x_] := debug[build, Just[x + 1]]
combine[x_] := debug[combine, Just[x + 1]]
clean[100] \[CirclePlus] build \[CirclePlus] combine
```

Out:

[image]