# Going full functional (Haskell style)

Tags: custom-notation, functional-style

I'm trying to define some notation so that Mathematica code would be more functional, similar to Haskell (just for fun): currying, lambdas, infix operator to function conversion, etc.. And I have some questions about it:

- Is it possible to make all Mathematica `h_[x1_,x2_,...]` functions to work as `h[x1][x2][..]`?
- Can I distinguish inside `Notation` box between `<+1>` and `<1+>`, how do I check for + there?
- How to define right-associate apply operator with highest precedence (`$`)?

This is what I have so far:

```
<< Notation`;

lapply[x_, y_] := x[y]
rapply[x_, y_] := x[y]
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\\"], lapply]
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["$"], rapply]
x_ \ y_ \ z_ := x[y][z]
x_ $ y_ $ z_ := x[y[z]]

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"λ", " ", "x__"}], "->", 
     "y_"}]] ⟺ ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"Function", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"{", "x__", "}"}], ",", "y_"}], "]"}]]]

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"〈", 
RowBox[{"op_", " ", "x_"}], 
     "〉"}]] ⟺ 
  ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"#", "op_", " ", "x_"}], "&"}]]]
AddInputAlias["f" -> ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"〈", 
RowBox[{"\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}], 
     "〉"}]]]

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"x_", " ", ".."}], " ", "y_"}], 
     "}"}]] ⟺ ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"Range", "[", 
RowBox[{"x_", ",", "y_"}], "]"}]]]

filter[f_][x_List] := Select[x, f]
map[f_][x__List] := Map[f, x]

filter\PrimeQ $ map\〈-1〉 $ map\ \
(λ x -> 2^x)\ {1 .. 100}
```

**EDIT**: Also did some kinda lazy lists, soon it will be haskell inside Mathematica :)

```
SetAttributes[list, HoldAll]
list[h_, l_][x_] := list[h, l[x]]
list[x_] := list[x, list]

map[f_][list] := list
map[f_][list[x_, xs_]] := list[f[x], map[f][xs]]

take[0][_] := list
take[_][list] := list
take[n_Integer][list[x_, xs_]] := list[x, take[n - 1][xs]]

range[n_Integer] := range[1, n]
range[m_, n_] := list[m, range[m + 1, n]]
range[n_, n_] := list[n, list]

show[list] := "[]"
show[list[x_, l_]] := ToString[x] <> "," <> show[l]

show $ (take[10] $  map\ (λ x -> x^2) $ range[10000])
```

Comment: I don't know what you want to *carry*, but the guy's name was **Haskell Brooks Curry** and the technique of transforming functions with several arguments is call *currying* ;-)

Comment: @halirutan I knew that! :)

Comment: Related: [Currying with _Mathematica_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5686494)

Comment: I prefer chutneys

Comment: swish, I haven't yet learned Haskell and as such I am not familiar with much of the syntax you aim to implement.  It would be very helpful at least to me if you would describe in some detail the syntax/behavior that you desire.  I chose not to attempt to debug your Notation Package code until I better understand what it is supposed to do. +1 for an interesting question, by the way.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Notation is mostly for sugar. The only problem with Notation is to make partial infix operators, like (+1), (2^), (~Mod~3), etc...

Comment: @swish Are the parentheses part of the syntax?  That should make it a lot simpler to implement!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes they are. `AngleBrackets` are also fine.

Comment: Re: lazy, see WReach's answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/838/5). Also don't miss the implementation of that answer as a package by sblom

Comment: A related issue: I wanted to add monad comprehensions to MMA and it has worked fairly well, though using the `Notation` package gave me some headaches (for example, in packages).  I've posted code in my answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46795/4811 in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's how I finally defined haskell operators:

```
rapply[x_] := x
rapply[x_, y__] := x[rapply[y]]
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["|"], rapply]

lapply[x_] := x
lapply[x__, y_] := lapply[x][y]
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["∘"], lapply]

InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["·"], Composition]
```

Now $\circ$, $\dot{}{}$ and | act exactly like haskell's space, . and $ respectfully. Also if we have only single left application then `@` is still helpful and it can be hidden with escape characters `:@:`.

And beautiful code like 
$\bf{show\cdot take\ 10\cdot map\ (\lambda\ x\to x{}^{\wedge}2)\cdot range | \infty }$ is possible. There are invisible `@`'s between *take* and *10*, *map* and ($\lambda\ x\to x{}^{\wedge}2)$. In haskell the same would look like $\bf{show . take\ 10.map(\backslash x->x{}^{\wedge}2)$[1..]}$.

With double left application, $\circ$ is necessary: $\bf{map\circ(\lambda\ x\to x+1)\circ \{1,2,3\}}$

**UPDATE**: I made this `TextCell` hack to make partial infix operators:

```
infix[f_String] := Block[{x,y},Head[ToExpression["x" <> f <> "y"]]]

〈TextCell[s_][x_]〉 := infix[s][#, x] &
〈x_[TextCell[s_]]〉 := infix[s][x, #] &
```

We again can use invisible `@` for application. Aliases can be made with `TextCell` on the left and on the right within `AngleBrackets` to enter them conveniently. Now stuff like <~Mod~10>, <2^>, <^3> also works.

Answer (score 20):

### Currying

I don't know if it is possible to make *all* functions work in the Currying form (`h[x1][x2][..]`) but it is at least possible to extend Hold behavior to all arguments which natively that pattern will not have.  I will copy my favorite method which I learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11561797/618728) by Grisha Kirilin:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAllComplete]

f[a_, b_, c_] := Hold[a, b, c]
f[a__] := Function[x, f[a, x], HoldAll]
```

Now:

```
f[2 + 2][8/4][7^0]
```

> ```
> Hold[2 + 2, 8/4, 7^0]
> ```

I think conceivably most other Attribute behaviors could be implemented, but the pattern-matching changes of e.g. `Orderless` might be prohibitively difficult.

#### Formatting

Following jVincent's lead, if we would like to format the intermediate expressions cleanly we could use:

```
MakeBoxes[Function[x$, h_[a__, x$], HoldAll], _] := ToBoxes @ HoldForm[h[a]]
```

Now:

```
f[2 + 2][8/4]
```

> ```
> f[2 + 2, 8/4]
> ```

This seems appropriate as `f` is already defined such that this form can be given as input.  However, if one prefers the visual form `f[2 + 2][8/4]` then we can use:

```
MakeBoxes[Function[x$, h_[a__, x$], HoldAll], _] := 
  ToBoxes[HeadCompose @@ HoldForm /@ Unevaluated[{h, a}]]

f[2 + 2][8/4]
```

> ```
> f[2 + 2][8/4]
> ```

(`HeadCompose` is a deprecated function but still quite useful.)
Note that in these rules I used `x$` which is the [automatic renaming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/121) of `x` that occurs within the `Function`.  This code could be made more robust by using a more unique symbol name.

### Low level Box forms

I cannot recall the limits of the Notation package in this regard, but you can determine how *Mathematica* parses an expression, and therefore what is accessible with `$PreRead` or `CellEvaluationFunction`, using a method from John Fultz (learned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/121)):

```
parseString[s_String, prep : (True | False) : True] := 
  FrontEndExecute[UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[s, prep]]
```

The default `True` should be used in our application as this is the form that will be seen by `$PreRead`, etc.  Testing your example expressions:

```
parseString @ "<+1>"
parseString @ "<1+>"
```

> ```
> {BoxData[RowBox[{"<", RowBox[{"+", "1"}], ">"}]], StandardForm}
>
> {BoxData[RowBox[{"<", RowBox[{"1", "+"}], ">"}]], StandardForm}
> ```

One can see that in isolation these parse to distinct forms.

### New operators

I described how to create a new operator in: [How can one define an infix operator with an arbitrary unicode character?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6355/how-can-one-define-an-infix-operator-with-an-arbitrary-unicode-character/6363#6363)

And a more mild example in: [Prefix operator with low precedence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6338/prefix-operator-with-low-precedence/6341#6341)

I recommend that you do not attempt to redefine the `$` symbol itself as your operator as this is extensively used internally in temporary symbol names (`Module`, `Unique`, etc.).

Comment: Very cool and simple "currying" definition. You can add something like `MakeBoxes[Function[arg_, f[a__, arg_], HoldAll], StandardForm] := 
 RowBox[{"f", "[", 
   Sequence @@ 
    Riffle[{ReleaseHold[
       Function[x, ToString[Unevaluated[x]], HoldAll] /@ 
        Hold[a]]}, "]["], "]"}]` to make it still look simple as long as it's still gathering parameters. I suspect it could be achieved in a more elegant fashion, but it demonstrate the idea.