# Can I view a package as a regular notebook?

Tags: notebooks, packages

How can I open a package as a normal notebook, i.e. without the toolbars and formatting of the built-in .m file interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon opening you can change the stylesheet and remove the docked cell:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> {},StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]
```

Then if you want to change the "Code" styles to something else, possibly "Input", do this:

```
NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "Code", All, CellStyle] 
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["StyleOther"]]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to save, is there a way around running this command manually every time I open the notebook?

Comment: Well perhaps that is a separate question - how to run a bit of code every time a notebook opens... what do you think?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way. Using the `parseString` function from [this answer of Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23818/going-full-functional-haskell-style/23831#23831), the following will create a notebook with an entire package's code being placed in a single Code - style cell:

```
parseString[s_String, prep : (True | False) : True] := 
   FrontEndExecute[UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[s, prep]]

ClearAll[openPackage];
openPackage[file_String?FileExistsQ] := 
  With[{stringCode = Import[file, "String"]},
     CreateDocument[
        Cell[First@parseString[stringCode, False], "Code"]
     ] /; stringCode =!= $Failed
  ]
```

For example:

```
openPackage@FileNameJoin[{FileNameDrop[FindFile["Combinatorica`"], -2], "Combinatorica.m"}]
```

You can split the code into multiple cells, but that would require a bit more work.